# Friend function doesn't compile as expected in C++Builder using newer Clang compiler

Tags: c++, c++builder, friend-function

```
class B;

class A
{
  protected:

  void DoStuff(B &b);
};

class B
{
  private:

  friend void A::DoStuff(B &b);
};
```

Compiles fine (and works as expected) using C++Builder 2009 (classic compiler).

C++Builder 11 (Clang compiler) however has an issue with `DoStuff()` being `protected` and does not compile.

Isn't the use of `friend` before the function in this case meant to work correctly?

The fix is easy, I know - simply put `friend B` in class `A`.
But I'd like to know if the usage of `friend` before a function can't be used as well in this context?  Perhaps using a different syntax?

Comment: Can't speak for Borland C++ Builder but you seem to be confused about what `friend` does to/for a function. It allows that function to access private/protected members of the class it befriends; it doesn't override the access **to** the function.

Comment: The reason is that `A::doStuff()` is not accessible to class `B`.     Choices are (1) make `A::doStuff()` public  (2)  derive `B` from `A`  or (3) declare `B` as a `friend` of `A`.    With all these options, this is a rather "smelly" design.   But you haven't described what you're trying to achieve (you're only specified what you want to compile) so there are probably better designs that don't rely on a protected member of one class being a friend of another

Comment: @Peter, I agree but at this stage I'm just recompiling using a newer compiler and I'm not that worried about this 20 years old piece of code that is only used in one place.  I just thought the syntax was fine, so I was puzzled.  PS. This code even predates BCB5 (I think a MS compiler was used to write the code back in the days).